# Проблема с ReferenceError: a is not defined

Tags: javascript, scope

Подскажите, почему возникает данная ошибка. Пишу вот такую функцию. В цикле видно переменную `b`, а переменную `а` не видно.

```
function movie(card, ticket, perc) {
    let cinemaVisit = 1;
    //first visit
    let а = ticket;
    let b = card + (ticket * (perc * cinemaVisit));
    while (а < b) {
        a += ticket; // тут ошибка Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
        b += ticket * (perc * cinemaVisit); // b видно
        cinemaVisit++;
    }
    return cinemaVisit;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас `a` с кирилицы. Поменяйте на `а` с латинского алфавита. В `while (a < b)`.

Comment: пожалуйста.....